# Localizable.strings is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization

I added a Localizable.strings to my project, but its not working... Here is a sample:

```
 NSLog(@"Welcome Text: %@", NSLocalizedString(@"WelcomeKey", @""));
```

The Localizable.strings:

```
Localizable.strings // DE    
"WelcomeKey" = "Willkommen!";
```

and

```
Localizable.strings // EN    
"WelcomeKey" = "Welcome!";
```

The Localization native development region is en

The NSLog in console is:

```
2013-05-11 04:45:49.552 App[13752:907] Welcome Text: WelcomeKey
```

Any ideas what's wrong ?

The localization from the Storyboard is working.

Codierung of both files are UTF-16

Answer (score 1):

Have you added a strings file to store the localized text. Click File > New > New File.
This link will be helpful to you. Please check this [localizable strings](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-localization-with-nslocalizedstring/).

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer maybe helpful to you:

1. Select the localized storyboard eg. Chinese (Simplified)
2. In File Inspector, toggle from “Localizable Strings” to “Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Storyboard”. This will retain the strings you already had, so you don’t have to worry.
3. Now, change it back to “Localizable Strings”, and things should be updated!

[Here to view original tutorial](http://samwize.com/2014/04/09/if-your-base-storyboard-with-localizable-dot-strings-is-not-working/)